# vscode setting for specific filename

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to apply a setting for a specific file, the only answers  I've seen for this topic have been language-specific settings. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, you cannot achieve this natively. According to their [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) they state:

> VS Code provides two different scopes for settings:
>
> - User Settings - Settings that apply globally to any instance of VS Code you open.
> - Workspace Settings - Settings stored inside your workspace and only apply when the workspace is opened.

You would have to file a feature request on their [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) for support