How to exclude package.json from automatic sorting in VSCode?
I'm using VSCode for a Node.js project, and I have set up my editor to automatically sort JSON files on save, using the following setting in my settings.json:
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.sort.json": "always"
}

I want to exclude package.json from being automatically sorted when I save it, while keeping the auto-sort feature for other JSON files in my project. Is there a way to specifically exclude package.json from the editor.codeActionsOnSave rule, or any other workaround that would allow me to achieve this behavior?
I looked into VSCode documentation and tried searching for similar issues but couldn't find a direct solution. Any suggestions or alternative approaches are greatly appreciated.

Are you using an extension for this?

"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084731/vscode-setting-for-specific-filename

OK, I've found a halfway decent way to integrate without hacking.

First remove the general setting "auto-sort" from your settings.json to ensure that it does not apply globally to all files. Here's what you should remove:

"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.sort.json": "always"
}


Next, reapply the setting specifically for JSON files (set Prettier as the default formatter):

"[json]": {
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.sort.json": "always"
  },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},


Classify package.json as jsonc (JSON with comments), which is not targeted by the auto-sort setting. Add this to your settings.json:

"files.associations": {
  "package.json": "jsonc"
}


Finally, set the default formatter for JSONC files, and deactivate auto-sort:

"[jsonc]": {
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.sort.json": "never"
  },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},

Until a more convenient solution is implemented by the VSCode developers, you can use this solution here.
Every JSON will be sorted and every JSONC not. You can extend this list below:
"files.associations": {
  "package.json": "jsonc", 
  "settings.json": "json"
}

With this setup, package.json remains untouched by the auto-sort feature, while files like settings.json continue to be sorted. This distinction hinges on the file extension — json for sorting, jsonc for no sorting.
Be aware of the last letter c
Another Example
  "files.associations": {
    "de.json": "json",  // sort
    "en.json": "json",  // sort
    "fr.json": "json",  // sort
    "nx.json": "jsonc", // do not sort
    "package.json": "jsonc", // do not sort
    "project.json": "jsonc", // do not sort
    "settings.json": "json", // sort
    "tsconfig.app.json": "jsonc", // do not sort
    "tsconfig.base.json": "jsonc", // do not sort
    "tsconfig.e2e.json": "jsonc", // do not sort
    "tsconfig.editor.json": "jsonc", // do not sort
    "tsconfig.json": "jsonc", // do not sort
    "tsconfig.lib.json": "jsonc", // do not sort
    "tsconfig.spec.json": "jsonc" // do not sort
  },


It'll be great to have an inline option to specify exactly which objects should be sorted on save e.g.:
// @keep-sorted
const someArray = ["foo", "elo", "bar"];

Wonder if any plugin does that (?)
